# is it possible to disable concurrent workflow execution at same time from admin console?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

In our project, at individual workflows, we have enabled concurrent workflow execution, that enables execution of the same workflow at the same time, and this can cause some issues.

There are 100's of such workflows. Is there a way to disable the concurrent workflow execution at the same time from admin console, so that we avoid having to disable it at each workflow?

This would save time and effort.

Comment: Disable concurrent workflow?

Comment: Yes I want to know if it's possible to disable concurrent workflow through admin console as there are 100's of workflows and disabling each of them is time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mass-editing workflows is not supported. And there is no global configuration to enable / disable concurrent execution.

One way might be: exporting => editing XML files => importing. Or using external scheduler to take care of it.